# MSVC list initialization ICE when used with structs?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, list-initialization, internal-compiler-error

This piece of code compiles well on gcc 8.1 and clang 6.0, but gives ICE on MSVC (both 2017 and 2018 pre-release):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Data {
    unsigned char data;
};

struct A {
    std::string x;
    Data y{255};
};

void f(std::vector<A> arg) {
}

int main() {
    f(std::vector<A>{{"Test"}});
}
```

Clearly, I've run into yet another MSVC compiler bug.

But to be really sure: Does the above code conform to standard C++, or have I made an error as well?

Comment: When you see _internal compiler **error**_, it is guaranteed to be a compiler error.

Comment: @PasserBy Yup, but that doesn't preclude the possibility of me making an error as well. I've had a number of MSVC ICEs that were also programmer errors before.

Comment: @Bernard Your code is indeed well-formed.

Comment: Made a bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/301777/ice-with-list-initialization-and-struct.html.  Somehow the code block in the editor there doesn't show as code when saved.